# Dividing data amongst 3 actionbar tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have an activity that has 3 actionbar sherlock tabs.  This activity has a long list of data that I want divided evenly amongst these 3 tabs.  The reason is since this list is long, it's easier for the user to find what he needs if the list is divided alphabetically amongst 3 tabs.

Clicking any tab shows the same list, just populated with different values, so I just wanted 1 fragment, called ListFragment that extends SherlockFragment.  In the ListFragment's onCreateView I want to create the adapter using the appropriate list via getActivity().getSecondList, etc.

How can this ListFragment know which tab was selected to grab the right list from it's containing activity?

```
public class SherlockTabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> implements TabListener {
private SherlockFragment mFragment;
private final SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;
private final String mTag;
private final Class<T> mClass;
private final int mfragmentContainerId;

public SherlockTabListener(int fragmentContainerId, SherlockFragmentActivity activity,
                           String tag, Class<T> clz) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mTag = tag;
    mClass = clz;
    mfragmentContainerId = fragmentContainerId;
}

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if(mTag.equals("AH")) {
            mFragment = ListFragment.newInstance(firstList);
        }
        else if(mTag.equals("IQ")) {
            mFragment = ListFragment.newInstance(middleList);
        }
        else
            mFragment = ListFragment.newInstance(lastList);

        ft.add(mfragmentContainerId, mFragment, mTag);

}
```

Comment: Use 3 instances of the same `ListFragment` and when the `Activity` creates each one, put something in the 'arguments' `Bundle` to tell each one what it's supposed to do. A `Fragment` has a method called `getArguments()` which is similar to an `Activity` calling `getIntent().getExtras()`.

Comment: the fragments are instantiated in the above listener; how do I access the lists to pass into newInstance()?

Comment: You should create a `Bundle` and add extras to it then call `setArguments(...)` on each `Fragment` before calling `ft.add(...)`.

Comment: how do I access the list to put in the bundle though, ft.add occurs in the SherlockTabListener